# Print directly through android device which accessing website through localhost

Tags: javascript, php, android, xampp, html

I have a laptop that is connected to printer through USB which is not WiFi or Bluetooth enabled and i am accessing the website in mobile through localhost by using Xampp, i want give print through mobile, is there any way to do this by pressing directly print button in website that I'm accessing in mobile phone ????

```
<input type=button class="btn btn-success form-control" name=print value="Print" onClick="window.print()">
```

Answer (score 0):

u just load the html website in webview which is hosted in xampp, then intercept the weppage with javascript interface to trigger the button click.
Refer: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview